# Can the questions and answers be displayed side by side on network profiles?

Tags: feature-request, network-profile

Somewhat related to this question: [In user profiles, why are questions given more weight than answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93205/in-user-profiles-why-are-questions-given-more-weight-than-answers)

Instead of displaying the top questions in-front of the top answers in the network profile, can we display them side by side? That way neither the questions or the answers will be hidden by each-other.

Comment: Why do you disagree with the answers posted to the linked question?